# Informatica Scorecard metric score

Tags: informatica

Hello I am new to Informatica Analyst. I am trying to create a scorecard in Informatica Analyst. I was told to use a rule. I am using the rule for completeness, where it checks for nulls and blanks. I was told to only use the field that is the outfield (output from rul) when I do the scorecard. The scorecard comes out green rather than red. It comes out all green, but all the data is null. Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong? I also changed the percentage, but instead of getting a long red bar, like I got when it was green the red bar is only about 1/16 inch long. With all of the data being incomplete, I thought I would get a long red bar.

Answer (score 1):

You can run and edit the scorecard in the Analyst tool. You can create and view a scorecard in the Developer tool. You can run the scorecard on current data in the data object or on data staged in the profiling warehouse.

You can view a scorecard in the Scorecards workspace. After you run the scorecard, you can view the scores on the **Scorecard** panel. You can select the data object and navigate to the data object from a score within a scorecard. The Analyst tool opens the data object in another tab.

You can perform the following tasks when you work with scorecards:

1. Create a scorecard in the Developer tool and add columns from a profile.
2. Optionally, connect to the Analyst tool and open the scorecard in the Analyst tool.
3. After you run a profile, add profile columns as metrics to the
   scorecard.
4. Optionally, configure the cost of invalid data for each metric.
5. Run the scorecard to generate the scores for columns.
6. View the scorecard to see the scores for each column in a record. Drill down
   on the columns for a score.
7. Edit a scorecard.
8. Set thresholds for each metric in a scorecard. Create a group to add
   or move related metrics in the scorecard.
9. Edit or delete a group, as required.
10. View the score trend chart for each score to monitor how the score changes over time.
11. Optionally, view the cost trend chart for each metric to monitor the value of data quality.
12. View scorecard lineage for each metric or metric group.

Comment: Thank you, do I do anything else for you to receive recognition?

Comment: And also mark the above Answer as 'Accepted' if it had resolved your question.